# Resign, resort etc, why is s pronounced as z?

Tags: pronunciation

Was wondering why we normally pronounce *resign* as *rezine*. *sign* is part of the words origin. Is it do distinguish it from 're-sign', to sign again?

Comment: Well,historically related word parts are not always pronounced the same. You can also compare "sign" to "signature," which has a third pronunciation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the phonological rules of English. An s that is written as one single letter between vowels is usually voiced /z/, e.g. laser, risible, resign, resort.

Comment: Rules??  I think you mean "observed tendencies".  English pronunciation has no "rules".

Comment: I hesitate even to say "usually." We should loose the hounds to chase down the obtuse who teach such abuse.

Comment: So if you wanted to say sort again, should that be re-sort?